# I'm trying pass a string from activity to fragment and gives the error "a null object reference"

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity, android-bundle

I don´t understand why don´t work, I've tested it in many different ways and it doesn't work ...
How I pass an string from activity to a fragment?

```
public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {

    Parque p = new Parque();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.teste);


        Bundle b = new Bundle();

        b.putString("StringVall","Hello:...");
        b.putInt("IntVal", 20);
        p.setArguments(b);
    }

}

public class Parque extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private Parque mExampleAdapter;
    private Context mContext;

    public Parque(){

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview, container, false);

        mContext = getActivity();

        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler);

       String val= getArguments().getString("StringVall");

       if(val!=null){
           Log.d("ok",val);
       }
       else if(val==null){
           Log.d("not work","...");
       }
       Toast.makeText(getContext(),"valor: " + val,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return view;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a interface to get the click from `ParqueAdapter`

```
interface RecyclerItemClick{
    void onItemClick(Parque parque);
}
```

Create an interface which fragment interaction

```
interface FragmentInteractionListener{
    // function to pass data
    void passData(Parque parque)
}
```

=> In `ParqueAdapter`

Declare an instance of `RecyclerItemClick` and create its setter

```
RecyclerItemClick listener

public void setListener(RecyclerItemClick listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

In `onBindViewHolder` method, call `onItemClick` method

```
public void onBindViewHolder(...) {
    holder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onItemClick(currentItem)
        }
    });
}
```

=> In the fragment which send datas (I'll call it `DataSenderFragment`)

declare a `FragmentInteractionListener` variable

```
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
```

Attach it to the instance of activty

```
@Override public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}
```

Implement `RecyclerItemClick`interface and set it to your adapter

```
public class SendDataFragment extends Fragment implements RecyclerItemClick{
    ...
    onCreate(...){
        ...
        // After instanciate adapter
        adapter.setListener(this);
    }

    @Override void onItemClick(Parque parque){

    }
}
```

Send data to your activity. This method is triggered after click event in adapter

```
@Override void onItemClick(Parque parque){
    mListener.passData(parque);
}
```

=> In your activity which manage fragment (`MainActivity` for example)

Implement `FragmentInteractionListener`

```
public class MainActivity implements FragmentInteractionListener{
    ...
    @override void passData(Parque parque){
    }
}
```

Pass data to your Map Fragment

```
@override void passData(Parque parque){
    Integer cod = currentItem.getCod();
    Integer ocup = currentItem.getOcupacao();
    ...
    FragmentTransaction tt = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    tt.replace(R.id.fragment_container,new MapaTeste.newInstance(cod, ocup);
    tt.commit();
}
```

=> In your Map Fragment

Create `newInstance` method for passing data to `MapaTeste` Fragment

```
public static newInstance newInstance(Integer param1, Integer param2) {
    Parque fragment = new Parque();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("data1", param1);
    args.putInt("data2", param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
  }
```

Finally retrieve datas like this

```
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
 super.onCreate(bundle);
 Bundle arguments = getArguments();
 if (arguments != null){
   Integer data1 = getArguments().getString("data1");
   Integer data2 = getArguments().getString("data1");
}
```

I hope it will be helpful !

Comment: sr Agnaramon I wuant send string from fragment to another fragment and not send to activity

Comment: How fragments are managed ? Both are visible on the activity or only one ?

Comment: I am using only one activity and several fragments

Comment: Ok. Are you using a ```FragmentManager``` for loading it ?

Comment: i was trying with activity but what i really need is when i click an item from a recyclerview send data to google maps fragment

Comment: Ok i see. You try to change fragment from your adapter. I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

declare your object of Parque in onCreate

```
public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {

        Parque p;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.teste);

            p = new Parque();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();

            b.putString("StringVall","Hello:...");
            b.putInt("IntVal", 20);
            p.setArguments(b);
        }

    }
```

Comment: if this answer is right thent please give an accepted answer.

Comment: doesn't work, gives the same error " java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference"

Comment: help me please, I don't know what to do more.

Comment: told me to use "Broadcast Receiver" but there is little information on the internet

Answer (score 0):

**error caused of you're getting unknown key that isn't existing..** put this code your your fragment where you're getting passed value override oncreate to fragment

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    Bundle arguments = getArguments();
    if (arguments != null && arguments.containsKey("StringVall")){
        //if key exists then do further action
        String val= getArguments().getString("StringVall");

    }

}
```

Comment: /Fragment "Parque" method "oncreateview"/                                                    Bundle arguments = getArguments();if (arguments != null&&arguments.containsKey("StringVall")){
        String val= getArguments().getString("StringVall");
    }

Comment: //classe Testar (Activity) public class Testar extends AppCompatActivity {
Parque_Fragment p;protected void onCreate(@Nullable BundlesavedInstanceState) {     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);setContentView(R.layout.teste); p = new Parque_Fragment();Bundle b =newBundle();b.putString("StringVall",".")p.setArguments(b); }}

Comment: I try your code: Bundle arguments = getArguments();
    if (arguments != null && arguments.containsKey("StringVall")){
        //if key exists then do further action 
        String val= getArguments().getString("StringVall");

    }                                                                                                                                   don´t work, String "val" don´t receive string "."

Comment: Can you send me your email / skype to send me print of the whole code?

Comment: Unfortunately not